# Get value from the NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, string

Getting complex String from the server

```
@"a:3:{i:0;s:4:\"3530\";i:1;s:4:\"3532\";i:2;s:4:\"4503\";}"
```

I need to all IDs from above string like

```
["3530", "3532", "4503"]
```

How can I get above output ? I know one way `componentsSeparatedByString` split string to array and get my result.

But I'm thinking it's not good way. So can you suggest me in right direction and `RGEX` or ETC.?

**NOTE :** It's not `JSON` String so we can't convert it to `Array` Or `Dictionary`.

---

I got expected result by my logic. But I don't like to do like below.

**Updated:**

```
 NSString *temStringValue = @"a:3:{i:0;s:4:\"3530\";i:1;s:4:\"3532\";i:2;s:4:\"4503\";}";
    NSArray * arrSplit = [temStringValue componentsSeparatedByString:@"4:\""];
    NSMutableArray *finalArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    if(arrSplit.count > 0 ){
        for (NSString *strInner in arrSplit) {
            NSArray * arrSplit2 = [strInner componentsSeparatedByString:@"\""];
            NSLog(@"%@", arrSplit2);
            [finalArray addObject:[arrSplit2 objectAtIndex:0]];
        }
    }

    [finalArray removeObjectAtIndex:0];
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:finalArray options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];
    NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@", jsonString
```

**Output**

```
[
  "3530",
  "3532",
  "4503"
]
```

So anybody have good ideas?

Comment: Is it a dictionary?

Comment: No it's string. If there were dictionary then we easily get result.

Comment: Your code looks OK. If it works, and the unit tests pass, then move on to another problem. Sure, regex would work here, but it would probably be slower than our solution at runtime, and future developers might find the regex difficult to understand and debug. (Reading other developers' regexes is often difficult unless they're well-commented)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a solution using Regular Expression

The pattern searches for a double quote followed by one or more non-double quote characters and a second double quote. The characters between the double quotes are captured in a group.

```
NSString* input = @"a:3:{i:0;s:4:\"3530\";i:1;s:4:\"3532\";i:2;s:4:\"4503\";}";
NSString *pattern = @"\"([^\"]+)\"";
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern options:0 error:nil];
NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:input options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, input.length)];
NSMutableArray *result = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {
    [result addObject: [input substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:1]]];
}
NSLog(@"%@", result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This code

```
NSString *temStringValue = @"a:3:{i:0;s:4:\"3530\";i:1;s:4:\"3532\";i:2;s:4:\"4503\";}";
    NSMutableArray * arrSplit = [[temStringValue componentsSeparatedByString:@"\""] mutableCopy];
    NSMutableArray *output = [NSMutableArray new];
    [arrSplit removeLastObject];
    [arrSplit enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id  _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
        if ( [(NSString *)obj containsString:@"s:4"] == false ) {
            [output addObject:obj];
        }
    }];
    NSLog(@"%@",output);
```

***Output***

```
(
3530,
3532,
4503
)
```

Answer (score 0):

As the values you're looking for are the only ones between `"`'s, you can use a very simple regular expression.

```
NSString *yourString = @"a:3:{i:0;s:4:\"3530\";i:1;s:4:\"3532\";i:2;s:4:\"4503\";}";

// Find occurrences of integer numbers between double quotes.
NSRegularExpression* regex = [[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern:@"\"([0-9]+)\"" options:0 error:nil];
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, [yourString length]);
NSArray* matches = [regex matchesInString:yourString options:0 range:range];

// Extract the found occurrences as strings.
NSMutableArray* output = [NSMutableArray new];
for (NSTextCheckingResult* match in matches)
{
    [output addObject: [yourString substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:1]]];
}
```